# Best way migrate from vaadin 7 to vaadin 24

Tags: migration, vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

The essence of the question is in the name.

I have a big legacy project on vaadin 7.7.15. There is a need to switch to the modern version of vaadin 24.

Are there any best practices besides rewriting from scratch? While I'm trying to upgrade to version 8 of the software https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8 to go from there to 24, but the further away, the more this idea seems to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no such "best way" for all vaadin users ;)

We did such a big bang migration from a vaadin 8 application (With vaadin7 compatibility classes active) to vaadin 23 in the first half of 2022.

Our lessons learned where:

- Depending on what data binding with vaadin you use, you will have to rewrite that part to use pojo's

  This includes all the grid/list renderers too, but many concepts can be taken over. That part is not complicated work, but it will probably touch many parts of your code, depending of your architecture
- The flow between screens has to (or better should) be rewritten to make use of the router features

  You can do it without rewriting this part, but you will miss some features like "BeforeViewEnter" etc. events or url parameter handling or have to reimplement the wheel or fight vaadin standard behaviour
- Missing addons, at least in spring 2022 we did lack many many used addons from the 7/8 versions or they did only work for v14

  In the last 12 months many addons have been upgraded/ported over to v23/v24, so this might not be an issue anymore, but this depends on what thirdparty addons you did use
- Most detail screens could easily be converted from v7/8 to 23 by replacing the imports and changing the event handler names/listeners

  This part was simpler than expected, but then we don't have that complex detail pages

Currently we are sheduling the upgrade to v24, which should not be that big an issue, but since it requires tomcat 10 and the jakarta imports instead of many javax imports, it will also require many udates to the imports and perhaps a few more changes

When we where going live with the v23 system, we had the v7/v8 system still running and using the same DB for 3-4 months.

So the users could use the new system, and if something did not work as expected, still do that part of the work in the old system.

I hope this helps you on your road with vaadin.

PS: Of course there is the MPR offer from Vaadin, where you can use existing v7/v8 parts in a v23 application, but for us this was

- too costly
- and we would have needed to either get rid of the v7 compatility layer by either go to full v8 or back down to v7. But since you are on v7, then should not be an issue

Comment: Thank you, in fact, I was trying to understand - does it make sense to gradually increase the version or immediately switch to 24

Comment: It makes no real difference if you go from v7 to v14 or to v23. You will have to do more or less the same, with the disadvantage that v14 will require one more step and you will not have so much addons as for v23. I'm not yet sure about directly going to v24, we will start the  v23->v24 planning in the next weeks, but probably you can directly go to v24

Comment: Excellent summary @AndréSchild  BTW. Do you remember the add-ons you were missing? I could maybe try to help maintainers to upgrade the ones still remaining.

Comment: At that time it was such basic stuff like Tooltips, DialogWindow, GridLayout etc. which have mostly been ported over since or implemented directly by Vaadin. So my recomendation is to go trough the used addons and look if a v23/v24 version exists, if not, then find a way arround it, or upgrading them

Comment: 7 to 23 then 23 to 24 makes more sense to me. You don't want to have to worry about upgrading other tech like servlets. MPR was a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

We're in the middle of a migration to Vaadin24+.

We never finished the Vaadin7 -> Vaadin8 migration, so we are migrating from  V8 with the V7 compatibility layer, straight to Vaadin24.

Based on that, I would recommend doing a clean V8 upgrade first. V8 mainly changed how data is accessed, and that is more or less unchanged in later versions.

Doing a clean V8 upgrade 1st was always our intention, but it was hard to prioritize when we had the compatibility layer and far too much to do.

Comment: Yes, the different data binding is one of the big changes, from my opinion you can also directly go to v24 and skip the v8 step, since there are some (smaller) changes in the data api between v8 and v14+ again.